# How does Slackware handle security updates?

Tags: linux, slackware

I use a distribution that uses apt for package management and am accustomed to letting apt grab a list of package changes. I generally let it install all the needed security updates.

I've been considering migrating to slackware. However, it seems slackware does not have a package management system. How would I learn about new security updates?

Is the only way to monitor http://www.slackware.com/security/?

Answer (score 6):

You can subscribe to security updates through several RSS feeds such as [Slackware Security Updates](http://dev.slackware.it/rss/slackware-security.xml) or subscribe to the maillist [Slackware Linux Project Mailing Lists](http://slackware.com/lists/).

Ultimately, the easiest is to use `slackpkg`.

When you first install Slackware, edit `/etc/slackpkg/mirrors` and select a mirror for your version of Slackware (13.37 or current) and your architecture (32 or 64 bit).

Then run `slackpkg update` to retrieve a list of possible updates and then `slackpkg upgrade-all` to install any updates.

Answer (score 3):

Slackware, contrary to rumor, [does in fact](http://www.slackbook.org/html/package-management.html) have a [package management system](http://www.slackware.com/config/packages.php):

> There's a myth that's been going around ever since RedHat debuted RedHat Package Manager, that Slackware has no package management tool. This simply couldn't be further from the truth. Slackware has always included a package manager, even before RedHat existed. While not as full-featured or as ubiquitous as rpm (or for that matter deb), pkgtool and its associated programs are every bit as good at installing packages as rpm. The truth about pkgtool is not that it doesn't exist, but that it doesn't do any dependency checking.

You may want to see [slapt-get](http://software.jaos.org/) as it is very similar to apt. To upgrade, you would run `slapt-get --upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Slackware has slackpkg included in the base installation. This tool is used to update the packages against the official slackware repository. The functionality is similar to slapt-get but it is generally intended only to get official packages for security updates.